# CDI @Instance to collect @Any, but access the Qualifiers (esp. @Named)

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, cdi

I want to collect all beans that are produced somewhere. Something like this:

```
static class Greeting {
    public final String text;

    public Greeting(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }
}

@Produces
@Named("hi")
Greeting hi = new Greeting("Hi");

@Produces
@Named("hello")
Greeting hello = new Greeting("Hello");

@Inject
Instance<Greeting> greetings;


@Test
public void shouldCollectAll() {
    Set<String> set = new HashSet<>();
    for (Greeting greeting : greetings) {
        set.add(greeting.text);
    }
    assertEquals(2, set.size());
    assertTrue(set.contains("Hi"));
    assertTrue(set.contains("Hello"));
}
```

I understand that I can select on the qualifiers like this:

```
@SuppressWarnings("all")
private static class NamedLiteral extends AnnotationLiteral<Named> implements Named {
    private final String name;

    public NamedLiteral(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String value() {
        return name;
    }
}

@Test
public void shouldCollectNamedHi() {
    Greeting greeting = greetings.select(new NamedLiteral("hi")).get();
    assertEquals("Hi", greeting.text);
}
```

But I want to access the qualifiers. Something like:

```
@Test
public void shouldCollectAllWithMeta() {
    Map<String, Greeting> map = new HashMap<>();
    for (Greeting greeting : greetings) {
        Annotated annotated = magic(greeting);
        String name = annotated.getAnnotation(Named.class).value();
        map.put(name, greeting);
    }
    assertEquals(2, map.size());
    assertEquals("Hi", map.get("hi"));
    assertEquals("Hello", map.get("hello"));
}
```

Is there a way to implement `magic` without writing a CDI extension? Or is there one out there? Or is this a feature request for CDI 2.0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to access the bean metadata from the bean contextual instances. However, this is possible when working at the level of the beans themselves, using the `BeanManager` instance and without writting a CDI extension, e.g.:

```
@Inject
BeanManager manager;

Set<Bean<?>> beans = manager.getBeans(Greeting.class, Named.class);

for (Bean<?> bean : beans) {
    String name = getQualifierOfType(bean.getQualifiers(), Named.class).value();
    map.put(name, greeting);
}

<Annotation, T extends Annotation> T getQualifierOfType(Set<Annotation> qualifiers, Class<T> type) {
    for (Annotation qualifier : qualifiers)
        if (type.isAssignableFrom(qualifier.getClass()))
            return type.cast(qualifier);

    return null;
}
```